# Custom font for action bar menu item

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu

We use menu items inside action bar. To set custom font type for action menu item, I used the below code. This works fine for Android version 5.0 and above but it is not working for the versions below 5.0. Could you please suggest the solution to set custom font for menu item below 5.0 versions.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/PrimeRegular.otf");
    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomMenuItemTypeface("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    menuItem.setTitle(mNewTitle);


public class CustomMenuItemTypeface extends TypefaceSpan {
     private final Typeface newType;
     public CustomMenuItemTypeface(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType); }}
```